# Pandas Series: finding row where relation holds between values in consecutive rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Let's say I have a series of 1s and 0s:

```
      value    
0     0 
1     1 
2     0 
3     0 
4     1 
5     1
```

What is the Pandorable way of finding:

- the first row where value is 1 (row 1)
- the first row where previous, current and next values are 0,0,1 (row 3)
- the last  row where previous, current values are 0,1 (row 4)
- all the rows where previous, current values are 0,1 (row 4,1)

In the case of 0s and 1s, I am currently joining the values and using regular expressions, but I believe in general, it would be a case of manual looping over the indices. Is there a better way?

Also, if there indeed exists a better way, does a similar solution exist also for dataframes, where your condition involves multiples columns?

Answer (score 1):

IIUIC, using `shift` and querying.

The first row where value is 1 (row 1)

```
In [486]: df[(df.value == 1)].head(1)
Out[486]:
   value
1      1
```

The first row where previous, current and next values are 0,0,1 (row 3)

```
In [487]: df[(df.value.shift(1) == 0) & (df.value == 0) & (df.value.shift(-1) == 1)]
Out[487]:
   value
3      0
```

The last row where previous, current values are 0,1 (row 4)

```
In [489]: df[(df.value.shift(1) == 0) & (df.value == 1)].tail(1)
Out[489]:
   value
4      1
```

All the rows where previous, current values are 0,1 (row 4,1)

```
In [490]: df[(df.value.shift(1) == 0) & (df.value == 1)]
Out[490]:
   value
1      1
4      1
```